# correlation between a continous variable and categorical variable?

Tags: correlation

I have a large data set with several columns. One of columns are continous and another one is categorical. Can you find the correlation between those columns?

Answer (score 0):

No. Assuming that you're talking about Pearson's correlation coefficient ($\rho$ or $r$), this only exists to measure the linear association between two quantitative variables. If one of your variables is categorical, then calculation the correlation is improper and likely impossible.